# How to use delegate property in MutableStateFlow in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-stateflow

I am using MutableStateFlow in my jetpack compose. Like below

```
val isBluetoothEnabled = MutableStateFlow(false)
```

whenever I tried to use the value of variable like this `.value` i.e. `isBluetoothEnabled.value`. So I am trying to use delegate property to avoid using `.value`

```
val isBluetoothEnabled by MutableStateFlow(false)
```

but I am getting weird error

```
Type 'MutableStateFlow<TypeVariable(T)>' has no method 'getValue(PairViewModel, KProperty<*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you should use var if you are going use delegate approach. Otherwise value can't be changed.

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.*

val isBluetoothEnabled by mutableStateOf(false)
   private set
```

This private set ensures that principles of unidirectional data flow are followed.

Then in your viewModel instead of writing `isBluetoothEnabled.value = true` you just write `isBluetoothEnabled = true`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use it as a delegate in your Composable, you'll have to add `.collectAsState()` to `StateFlow`, otherwise Compose cannot detect state changes and therefore cannot update the value when necessary :)

Also if you only handle/update this value within the UI (and not a ViewModel for example), simply use `mutableStateOf(false)`

Answer (score -1):

You should use this method

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.collectAsState
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.asStateFlow


class TestViewModel constructor(
    
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _isBluetoothEnabled = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val isBluetoothEnabled = _isBluetoothEnabled.asStateFlow()

}
@Composable
fun Sample1(
    viewModel: TestViewModel 
) {
    val isBluetoothEnabled = viewModel.isBluetoothEnabled.collectAsState()
    
}
```